# Vue3: why a componment instance template ref unable to find defined function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

LoginAccount.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { rules } from './config/AccountConfig'
import { reactive } from 'vue'
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { ElForm } from 'element-plus';
const account = reactive({
  name: '',
  password: ''
})
const formRef = ref<InstanceType<typeof ElForm>>()


const loginAction = () => {
  console.log("开始登录")
  formRef.value?.validate((valid) => {
    if (valid) {
      console.log("登录逻辑")
    }
  })
}
// 规则

</script>
```

LoginPanel

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import LoginAccount from './LoginAccount.vue'
import LoginPhone from './LoginPhone.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'
const isKeepPassword = ref(false);

const accountRef = ref<InstanceType<typeof LoginAccount>>()



const handleLoginClick = () => {
  console.log("立即登录")

  accountRef.value?.loginAction() No property exists " loginAction"
}
</script>
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ctf6.png)
How do I type the imported component, so that when I call its methods through refs, it checks exposed method names and types of passed arguments?

accountRef.value?.loginAction() No property exists " loginAction"

how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

[Docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose)

> Components using `<script setup>` are closed by default - i.e. the public instance of the component, which is retrieved via template refs or `$parent` chains, will not expose any of the bindings declared inside `<script setup>`

> To explicitly expose properties in a `<script setup>` component, use the `defineExpose` compiler macro

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { rules } from './config/AccountConfig'
import { reactive } from 'vue'
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { ElForm } from 'element-plus';
const account = reactive({
  name: '',
  password: ''
})
const formRef = ref<InstanceType<typeof ElForm>>()


const loginAction = () => {
  console.log("开始登录")
  formRef.value?.validate((valid) => {
    if (valid) {
      console.log("登录逻辑")
    }
  })
}
// 规则

defineExpose({
  loginAction,
})

</script>
```

Comment: very very thanks you, i solve it